# Need to Import 3 databases from 3 different sites into a 4th database located on the same server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have been working on this problem for months and have not found a workable solution.

**Goal:**

I need to copy / import 1 table from each of 3 different databases located on 3 different sites (domains) into a 4th database located in another domain located within my hosting account. **This needs to be accomplished via cron every hour.**

Each of the 3 databases contains 1 table with 16 fields. All 3 databases are identical except for the data in the rows are different.

```
Database1 - Post_Data table on site1.com
Database2 - Post_Data table on site2.com
Database3 - Post_Data table on site3.com
```

Database4 on site4.com contains the following 4 empty tables:

```
Post_Data
Temp_Data1
Temp_Data2
Temp_Data3
```

I would like to copy / import the following into Database4:

```
Post_Data table from site1.com into Temp_Data1 table
Post_Data table from site2.com into Temp_Data2 table
Post_Data table from site3.com into Temp_Data3 table
```

If this could have be done, I would have later merged the data in tables Temp_Data1, Temp_Data2, Temp_Data3 into the Post_Data table.

I have tried doing this method by running a PHP / MySQL script on site4.com but ran into problems due to connection permission across all the domains.

To get around this connection permission problem I tried another method that copies the 3 site databases from site1.com, site2.com, and site3.com to site4.com so that they all reside within the same domain (site4.com). This way I can then import the each of the 3 databases into 3 new databases within site4.com. The last step (step 3), importing the .sql file failed causing a 500 server error.

Site4.com's 3 New Databases contain on 1 empty table each:

```
Database_a - Post_Data table
Database_b - Post_Data table
Database_c - Post_Data table
```

Note: I found the following scripts online via searches.

**Step 1:** Backup each database file from site1.com, site2.com, and site3.com by running the following backup_database_file.php script on each of the 3 sites from each of the 3 sites.

**backup_database_file.php (i.e. for site1.com)**

```
<?php
// Database Backup for site1.com
// Run via site1.com
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'datsabase');
define('DB_USER', username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('BACKUP_SAVE_TO', '/home/site1/public_html/tempDBs'); // without trailing slash
$backupFile = BACKUP_SAVE_TO . '/' . DB_NAME .'.sql.gz';
$command = 'mysqldump --opt -h ' . DB_HOST . ' -u ' . DB_USER . ' -p\'' . DB_PASSWORD . '\' ' . DB_NAME . ' | gzip > ' . $backupFile;
system($command);
?>
```

**Results:**

```
site1.com
 - tempDBs (folder)
   - database1.sql.gz (database backup file)
site2.com
 - tempDBs (folder)
   - database2.sql.gz (database backup file)
site3.com
 - tempDBs (folder)
   - database3.sql.gz (database backup file)
```

===========================================================================

**Step 2:** Copy each of the 3 site1.com, site2.com, and site3.com database files to the tempDBs folder on site4.com

**copy_databases.php**

```
<?php
// Copy database files
// Run via site4.com
$source1 = "http://site1.com/tempDBs/database1.sql.gz";
$destin1 = "/home/site4/public_html/tempDBs/database1.sql.gz";
$source2 = "http://site2.com/tempDBs/database2.sql.gz";
$destin2 = "/home/site4/public_html/tempDBs/database2.sql.gz";
$source3 = "http://site3.com/tempDBs/database3.sql.gz";
$destin3 = "/home/site4/public_html/tempDBs/database3.sql.gz";
copy($source1, $destin1);
copy($source2, $destin2);
copy($source3, $destin3);
?>
```

**Results:**

```
site4.com
 - tempDBs (folder)
   - database1.sql.gz (database backup file)
   - database2.sql.gz (database backup file)
   - database3.sql.gz (database backup file)
```

===========================================================================

**Step 3:** Since the following script is for importing **.sql** files into a database, I had to manually uncompress and upload the **database1.sql.gz** file to **database1.sql**. Next, I ran the following import script, but received a 500 server error. By the way, the uncompressed database file database1.sql is 120 MB.

**import_database.php**

```
<?php
// Run via site4.com for importing database1 into database_a

//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='database_a';
$mysqlUserName ='username1';
$mysqlPassword ='password1';
$mysqlHostName ='site4.com';
$mysqlImportFilename ='database1.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Import the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
break;
case 1:
echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
?>
```

If you know a better way to do this, please let me know. At this point I cannot change any of the databases on site1.com, site2.com, and site3.com. **Keep in mind that this process would need to be accomplished via cron every hour.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be more confortable using a tool to do this? Because there is a tool to do exactly this kind of thing named: MySQLMigrationTool

Comment: Keep in mind that this process would need to be accomplished via cron every hour.

Comment: Are you calling this php from a browser? The 500 error is instantly or take some time? Maybe the error 500 is because of `timeout` (some apache or php configuration). If the error is because of timeout you could call your php script over command line.

Comment: running the script from a browser. It takes some time, so it probably a time out

Comment: So then you have three options: 1 - Alter apache/php configuration increasing the timeout parameter; 2 - You create a bash script and call it from your php site on domain 4 or 3 - Run it from command line  using php. it probably will run

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a feed service on each of the sites that has a method that accepts a time stamp argument and will respond with the data added after that time stamp?  then just write a tool that calls that service and dumps the results into your master db.